# How to anti-diagonalize a matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

Given a matrix `M`, i.e.:

```
M = {{0, 0, a, b}, {0, 0, c, d}, {e, f, 0, 0}, {g, h, 0, 0}};
```

how can I use *Mathematica* to anti-diagonalize this matrix? By anti-diagonalization I mean a result such as:

`res = {{0,0,0,e[1]},{0,0,e[2],0},{0,e[3],0,0},{e[4],0,0,0}}`

where the `e[i]` are the anti-diagonal values which make matrices `res` and `M` similar to each other.

**EDIT:**

Note that:

```
res.res
```

> `{{e[1] e[4], 0, 0, 0}, {0, e[2] e[3], 0, 0}, {0, 0, e[2] e[3], 0}, {0,
>      0, 0, e[1] e[4]}}`

which means that the eigenvalues of `res` are `+Sqrt[e[1]e[4]], -Sqrt[e[1]e[4]], +Sqrt[e[2]e[3]], -Sqrt[e[2]e[3]]`, which makes the ordering of the anti-diagonal values `e[i]` in pairs important.

**EDIT2:**

With the following explicit example we can see that using a characteristic polynomial `Det[M-Reverse/@IdentityMatrix[4]x]` actually cannot lead to a similar matrix:

```
M = {{0, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 0, 0}};
Eigenvalues[M]
% // N
```

> [image]

```
list = x /. Solve[Det[M - Reverse /@ IdentityMatrix[4] x] == 0, x];
Sqrt[(# /. List -> Times &) /@ Subsets[list, {2}] //Expand // Simplify]
% // N
```

> [image]

We see that none of the resulting pairs `Sqrt[e[i]e[j]]` are equal to any of the four eigenvalues of `M`. Therefore, the procedure does not work and we should look for something else.

Comment: What are "antidiagonal eigenvalues"? Are they defined by the existence of a antidiagonal matrix which is similar to $M$?

Comment: @anderstood Yes, I am just interested in anti-diagonalizing the matrix. The use of a term like "antidiagonal eigenvalues" was unfortunate. I will remove it.

Comment: Isn't your question about maths more than mathematica? Also, only a "few" matrices are "anti-diagonalizable". For example, if I am not mistaken, no $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ whose diagonal elements are not opposite ($m_{11}\neq -m_{22}$) is "anti-diagonalizable".

Comment: @anderstood Interesting, I did not know that. At corey979 : You are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
M = {{0, 0, a, b}, {0, 0, c, d}, {e, f, 0, 0}, {g, h, 0, 0}};

anti1 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 4}, Automatic, {1, -1}] -> x, {4, 4}];

M - anti1 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Solve[Det[M - anti1] == 0, x]
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, I would also like to maintain a correct order of the eigenvalues `x` from top right to bottom left. With a characteristic polynomial we get the values, but not the order?

Comment: No. First, in the above there are only symbols. How do you want to order them? I mean, consider `w` and `w+z` - which one is smaller? Any answer you give I'll falsify by providing some values of `w, z`. Second, there is no _correct order_ when it comes to diagonalization - the eigenvalues have to correspond to their eigenvectors. Period. The algebra is correct when you place the first eigen-(value AND vector) in the first, second, of 137th column.

Comment: Finally, if you want the numerical values in some order, you can use `ReplaceAll` and `SortBy` to obtain them in that order, and then construct the anti-diagonal matrix. // You'd have to provide a mathematical theory of such anti-eigenvalues and anti-eigenvectors. What relation should the anti-eigenvector matrix obey with the original matrix `M`? Etc.

Comment: Aaand - what's the _correct order_ for **complex** eigenvalues?

Comment: While for a diagonal matix simultaneous exchange of two rows and columns is a similarity transformation, doing so for an anti-diagonal matrix is not. Label `x1,x2,x3,x4` from bottom-left to top-right. To exchange `x1<->x2` we have to exchange columns `1<->2` and rows `3<->4`. While this is a similarity transformation, it also exchanges `x3<->x4`. So the order of `xi` is important, in pairs.

Comment: The above is because the actual *diagonal* eigenvalues of the anti-diagonal matrix are $\pm\sqrt{x_1 x_4}$ and $\pm\sqrt{x_2 x_3}$. Therefore, loosing track of how to pair these anti-diagonal values will corrupt the actual eigenvalues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51724/discussion-between-corey979-and-kagaratsch).